# need timerStartDate of timer and timerconfig ejb3.0

Tags: timer, ejb-3.0

I have a TimerConfig and a Timer Object and use EJB 3.0. All works well, but "**onTimeout**" I want to get the information, when the timer was initialized. I cannot find a method such as **timerStartDate**.

Should I use timerConfig.setInfo and put the date when timer is initialized? Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to know when createTimer was called, then you'll have to store it in setInfo.  There is no builtin mechanism.